# how to create a new type with custom bytes in C?

Tags: c, byte

Is it possible to create a new type in C that uses the amount of bytes that I decide? 
I know that an int takes 4 bytes, but I need to work with very small numbers so allocating 4 bytes with malloc for every int is a bit of a waste, i was thinking of creating a new type for numbers that takes only 1 byte...if it's possible

Comment: *new type for numbers that takes only 1 byte* - it's called `char` in C.

Comment: Are you talking about `int8_t` or `uint8_t` which are part of `inttypes.h`?

Comment: "I know that an int takes 4 bytes".... I think that an `int` takes as many bytes as your implementation is happy with. It's the fastest general purpose data type, and it is often 32 bits on today's CPUs, but that is far from certain.

Comment: *but I need to work with very small numbers so allocating 4 bytes with malloc for every int is a bit of a waste* Why do you think you need to use `malloc` at all for integer values? For that, you'd need both the data and a pointer to that data, and you'd pass the value of the pointer around to access the data.  Just pass the value directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `char` instead of `int`

Or, you can create `structure`, it is the most commonly used custom data type in C.
For example:

```
struct customStructure {
    char c;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create a new type in C that uses the amount of bytes that I decide?

Yes, you can declare an array of `char` (or `signed char` or `unsigned char`) of any positive length you like, up to an implementation-dependant (but usually large) limit.

> I know that an int takes 4 bytes,

You are mistaken: an `int` *may* take four bytes, but the standard does not require that.  Its minimum required range can be represented with only two bytes, and some implementations indeed provide two-byte `int`s.  That was more common historically than it is today.  Also, implementations can make `int` *larger* than four bytes.  That's rare as a default, but some compilers provide an option to produce that result.

> but I need to work with very small numbers so allocating 4 bytes with malloc for every int is a bit of a waste, i was thinking of creating a new type for numbers that takes only 1 byte...if it's possible.

A one-byte number is a `signed char` or `unsigned char`.  Technically, plain `char` also qualifies, but its signedness is implementation-defined, and as a matter of style, it is preferable to reserve its use to character data.  Also, technically, `char` and its signed and unsigned variations may be larger than 8 bits, but you are unlikely ever to run into a C implementation where that is the case, and C anyway offers no smaller data type.

Comment: apparently we, as programmers cannot create a type with a specific amount of bits, do we?

Comment: @Velaro, C provides for structures to have bitfield *members*, whose values are represented by a specific number of bits (subject to limits).  But that's a different question from *storage size*.  In C, the size of type `char` is the unit in which storage sizes are measured, and there are no non-integral storage sizes.  In paractice, that usually aligns with the underlying machine's ability to address storage.

Answer (score 1):

A byte type already exits, it is called `char`, and `sizeof(char)=1`, so strictly talking about datatypes, `char` is the smallest amount of memory you can manage though C.

However, if you are talking about bits, it doesn't mean that `char` type is always 8bits (it is common a byte of 10 or 16bit in DSPs). Given that, the number of bits in a `char` is indicated by `CHAR_BIT`.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, an `int` has at least 2 bytes, according to the C standard, and the actual width of a type is machine-dependent. If you want numeric types with a certain width, I suggest you take a look at those defined in `<stdint.h>`.

If you *really* want to use a type with, say, N bytes, you could use `char small_numbers[N]` and get your hands dirty with some bit twiddling, but the more practical solution would be to simply use the built-in types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below structures for bytes and bits respectively.

```
 typedef struct data_type_bytes {
        unsigned char data;
 } bytes;

typedef struct data_type_bits{
   unsigned int heightValidated : 1;
} bits;
```